# MVC Controllers in Identity Server 3 can not use DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, identityserver3

I have some custom screens on my Identity Server 3 related to user registration process. They are implemented using MVC. I have added some controllers with views and models. I have reached a point where I want to inject some dependencies in my controller as follows:

```
 private readonly IMailDeliveryService _mailDeliveryService;

 public CreateUserAccountController(IMailDeliveryService mailDeliveryService)
 {
     this._mailDeliveryService = mailDeliveryService;
 }
```

I used the "out-of-the-box" dependency resolver that they have - Autofac.

```
app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
{
    var corsPolicyService = new DefaultCorsPolicyService()
    {
        AllowAll = true
    };

    var idServerServiceFactory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                    .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());

    // ...

    idServerServiceFactory.Register(new Registration<IMailDeliveryService, MailDeliveryService>());

    var options = new IdentityServerOptions
    {
        Factory = idServerServiceFactory,
        // ...
        },
        // ...
    };

    idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
});
```

When I try to make a request and try to instatiate my controller I get:

```
IdentityServer.Controllers.CreateUserAccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

I believe the issue is that MVC and OWIn have kind of a different pipelines but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Identityserver 3 uses a custom view engine. That uses the bindings you've shown. MVC does not have DI built in. You need to configure it separately. If you want to use AutoFac, then I'm sure there's docs on how to set it up.